# Sending a Torrent magnet link using the Deluge JSON API

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, json

I have built this script that sends a magnet link to the client. As I never ever had any proper programming lessons I would want to ask you if this approach is good, if I am missing something, There are parts of the script that are handled off-side, link checking, login credentials etc. What I have been thinking is that I could maybe create a JSONobject that will be accessible overall and for each request I would just set its fields and make the request. Or is my approach with methods generating the JSONobject and later turning it into a string good enough?

```
namespace TorrentSwitch.managers.Deluge
{

class Deluge
{

    public static CookieAwareWebClient c;
    public static string URL;

    public static void InitializeWebClient()
    {
        c = new CookieAwareWebClient();
        c.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        c.Headers.Set("content-type", "application/json");
    }


    public static void GetURL(Settings currentClient)
    {
        URL = "http://" + currentClient.hostname + ":" + currentClient.port + "/json";

    }

    private static byte[] BuildRequest(string method, string parameter, bool isTorrentRequest = false)
    {
        JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();
        jarrayObj.Add(parameter);

        if (isTorrentRequest)
        {
            JObject torrentExtraObject = new JObject();
            jarrayObj.Add(torrentExtraObject);
        }

        JObject X = new JObject(
                            new JProperty("method", method),
                            new JProperty("params", jarrayObj),
                            new JProperty("id", "1"));

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(X, Formatting.None);
        byte[] request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);

        return request;
    }

    private static byte[] SendRequest(string method, string parameter, bool IsTorrentRequest = false)
    {
        byte[] response = c.UploadData(URL, "POST", BuildRequest(method, parameter, IsTorrentRequest));

        return response;
    }

    public static string ResponseToString (byte[] response)
    {
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        using (GZipStream g = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(response), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {

            g.CopyTo(output);
        }
        string JsonResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());

        return JsonResponse;

    } 

    public static bool SendMagnetURI(Settings currentClient, string magnet)
    {
        InitializeWebClient();
        GetURL(currentClient);
        try
        {
            //Authorization
            string authorization = ResponseToString(SendRequest("auth.login", currentClient.password));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //TorrentAdding
        string addingTorrent = ResponseToString(SendRequest("core.add_torrent_magnet", magnet, true));

        if (currentClient.label != String.Empty)
        {
            CheckForLabel(currentClient.label);
        }

        return true;

    }
}
}
```

settings class, it have been made by a friend partly as back then I couldnt get my head around it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TorrentSwitch.torrent_clients
{
    public static class client
    {
        //This can be made static so you can access it all over your application, but remeber to check if it has
        //members before trying to access any of them.
        public static List<Settings> users = new List<Settings>();

        public static void Loop()
        {
            foreach (var setting in users)
            {
                //Loop them here and access them using setting.variable
                Debug.WriteLine(setting.alias);
            }
        }

        public static void removeUser(string alias)
        {
            users.Remove(GetByAlias(alias));
        }

        public static Settings GetByAlias(string alias)
        {
            //Will return the first Settings where the alias set in that class matches the alias you provied. 
            //Can also return null if none is existent.
            return users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.alias == alias);
        }

        public static void AddUser(Settings setting)
        {
            //Make sure the setting is not null before trying to add it to the list.
            if (setting != null)
            {
                users.Add(setting);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("setting can not be null");
            }
        }

        public static void AddUser(string alias, string hostname, string port, string username, string password, ClientType theClientType, string path,
            string label)
        {
            //Could be a good idea to check that none of the variable is null
            users.Add(new Settings
            {
                alias = alias,
                username = username,
                password = password,
                hostname = hostname,
                port = port,
                label = label,
                path = path,
                ManagerClientType = theClientType
            });
        }

    }
    public class Settings
    {
        //I would put this in uppercase and not lowercase.
        public string alias { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string hostname { get; set; }
        public string port { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public ClientType ManagerClientType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ClientType
    {
        uTorrent,
        Deluge,
        Transmission
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Settings class as well?

Comment: added it now. even tho it wasnt entirely made by me

Comment: It seems that the code in question either is not complete. I miss at least the `CheckLabel ()` method.

Comment: As long as you maintain it it is ok

Comment: Yes it's work in progress as the deluge program is not behaving as it should

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your naming (especially in `Settings`): C# `public` members should always be named `PascalCase` (first letter of each word capitalized).

---

Next, you have:

> ```
> public static CookieAwareWebClient c;
> public static string URL;
> ```

Generally, you should never have any `public` fields (a field is written like the two items above, no `get; set;` etc.), you should always make `public` fields a property instead. Just as well, `c` should be renamed `Client` or another meaningful name.

```
public static CookieAwareWebClient Client { get; set; }
public static string URL { get; set; }
```

---

In the following case:

> ```
> if (currentClient.label != String.Empty)
> ```

It's probably better to use `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentClient.label))` here. It can be a cheaper call (sometimes, not always) but conveys the same meaning.

---

You use an `enum` (which is great):

> ```
> public enum ClientType
> {
>     uTorrent,
>     Deluge,
>     Transmission
> }
> ```

But you violate naming conventions. C# `enum` naming is `PascalCase` for the `enum` name and all values. (So `uTorrent` would be `UTorrent` or `Utorrent`.)

---

If you have access to C#6.0, the following:

> ```
> public static List<Settings> users = new List<Settings>();
> ```

Becomes:

```
public static List<Settings> Users { get; } = new List<Settings>();
```

If not, then you simply need:

```
private static List<Settings> _users = new List<Settings>();
public static List<Settings> Users { get { return _users; } }
```

---

Regarding:

> ```
> public static void removeUser(string alias)
> {
>     users.Remove(GetByAlias(alias));
> }
> ```

Again, `public` member naming dictates it should be `RemoveUser` instead.

---

In C# a `namespace` should follow `PascalCase` naming conventions:

> ```
> namespace TorrentSwitch.torrent_clients
> ```

Should be:

```
namespace TorrentSwitch.TorrentClients
```

---

If you have access to C#6.0 (Visual Studio 2015+) then some methods which are a single, simple `return` can become an expression-bodied member, example:

> ```
> public static Settings GetByAlias(string alias)
> {
>     //Will return the first Settings where the alias set in that class matches the alias you provied. 
>     //Can also return null if none is existent.
>     return users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.alias == alias);
> }
> ```

To:

```
//Will return the first Settings where the alias set in that class matches the alias you provied. 
//Can also return null if none is existent.
public static Settings GetByAlias(string alias) =>
    users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.alias == alias);
```

---

I tend to leave *at least* one space after the double-slash in my comments:

> ```
> //Will return the first Settings where the alias set in that class matches the alias you provied.
> ```

To:

```
// Will return the first Settings where the alias set in that class matches the alias you provied.
```

It makes them easier to read, especially in large blocks.

---

You can make use of `var` in *a great deal many* places of your code.

You have an example here:

> ```
> public static void Loop()
> {
>     foreach (var setting in users)
>     {
>         //Loop them here and access them using setting.variable
>         Debug.WriteLine(setting.alias);
>     }
> }
> ```

Anywhere the type is a given, you can replace with `var`:

> ```
> private static byte[] SendRequest(string method, string parameter, bool IsTorrentRequest = false)
> {
>     byte[] response = c.UploadData(URL, "POST", BuildRequest(method, parameter, IsTorrentRequest));
>
>     return response;
> }
> ```

To:

```
private static byte[] SendRequest(string method, string parameter, bool IsTorrentRequest = false)
{
    var response = c.UploadData(URL, "POST", BuildRequest(method, parameter, IsTorrentRequest));

    return response;
}
```

Which can then become:

```
private static byte[] SendRequest(string method, string parameter, bool IsTorrentRequest = false) =>
    c.UploadData(URL, "POST", BuildRequest(method, parameter, IsTorrentRequest));
```

With C#6.0. There are other examples, I challenge you to find them all. :)

---

Your code doesn't look *too* bad, you should fix your whitespace though. Generally a maximum of one line where it's necessary.

---

Also: I apologize if anything came off harsh, I mean no rudeness I just happen to be really tired (reviewing at 01:45AM may *not* be a good idea) and I think this is a *very* good start. Hopefully you explore more with C# and become a great programmer in it! :)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't create static classes like the `client` or the `Deluge` if they require state e.g. the `c` (cookie client) or the `users` list. Static classes should only be used if they provide general stateless reusable and independent functions.

Static classes with state are very hard to test because you'd need to call the tests in a very specific order or otherwise they will overwrite eachothers state and the test results will be unreliable and not repetable.

The `Deluge` and `client` classes should be instantiable so that each test can have its own instance and not affect other test results.

You know all about naming and style from [@EBrown's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153003/59161) so I'll skip it.

---

Currently all APIs in the `Deluge` and `client` classes are publicly accessible but they shouldn't. Such methods as the `InitializeWebClient` or the `Loop` aren't very useful for the user. He should not know them.

If you make to many APIs public users may really start using them and you cannot remove them easily anymore especially if they are only meant to support other methods and class' internal logic.

Read about and use the access modifiers responsibly and declare everything as non-public (private, internal, protected) that doesn't have any value for the user of your classes, even if it is only you who uses them.

Public APIs that shouldn't be public only unnecessarily polute IntelliSense with additional methods that have no use elsewhere. The benefit of having private methods is that you can change, remove or add them at anytime without breaking anything publicly used. Private methods only support public APIs. Most of the time they are not very useful on their own and may actually break something if called unexpectedly.